# How to put many small vertex buffers into GPU memory efficiently

Tags: opengl, opengl-es

I have some tiny objects using 4-8 vertices. Currently they use client side memory (I'm using OpenGL 2.1/OpenGL ES 2.0) but I want to use VBO (and optionally VAO) to be more compatible with WebGL 1.0 and newer GL versions.

Is there any recommended practice to do this without sacrificing performance and wasting GPU memory?

If my objects are static and use the same vertex configuration then I can put them all into a single VBO and use offset in DrawArrays. But what to do if they are different (still possible to use VBO, but not VAO) or when they are dynamic (allocate one VBO and orphan it on every write?)?

Especially interesting what to do with different vertex configurations (use one VBO and multiple VAO)?

How such cases are handled in modern GL?

Comment: @Rabbid76 Are you removing the opengl flag is correct here? It seems that they are using OpenGL ES 2.0 now, but would like to adapt it to "regular" modern OpenGL.

Comment: Does [this](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Specification_Best_Practices) help? I would start with multiple VAOs, one VBO and update it using glBufferSubData.Then measure the performance. I don't think you can get a more specific answer, given your problem statement.

Comment: Normally you'd single out a small finite set of various vertex formats and use that many VAOs. If the objects are truly fully dynamic, you'll write out each object to the VBO of its respective VAO, sending the data in one glBufferSubData call or through memory mapping once per frame. That would be analogous to what you do with OpenGL 2.1, but more efficient due to less overhead.